# Why I get runtime error when I get request data in .Net Framework (not Core) with gPRC?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, grpc, runtimeexception

I use lib Grpc.Core.
My code:

```
 var uri = new Uri(url);
 _channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(uri.Host, uri.Port, Grpc.Core.ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
 _client = new Provider.ProviderClient(_channel);
 //...
```

When I call this code I get a runtime exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

My "Provider" was written on .Net 5. But this code in old project and I can use only .Net Framework.

Help me please.

Comment: It looks like you're using code built with `.net standard 2.1` which is not available for the legacy `.Net Framework` (which only supports `.net standard 2.0`). If you've built a library on `.net standard 2.1` try retargeting it for `.net standard 2.0`. Also, your legacy code has to target `.net framework 4.8` I believe (maybe it was `4.7` I cant remember)

Comment: OK so `net standard 2.0` can be used with the legacy `.net framework 4.6.1` but `MS` recommends that you retarget your legacy application to at least `4.7.2` for the best experience.

Comment: @WBuck : For net to run you need the Net library installed on the machine.  The core library is a compact library where the net is in one dll file instead of multiple dlls.  The reason for using Net 4.7.2 is it has the capability to target a c# application to either the core library or the net library.

Comment: @WBuck Tell me please how to find libraries which use .net standard 2.1. And how to retarget them. Thanks.

Comment: I can use framework 4.8. I selected it